# Setting source property when binding bitmap image to database

Tags: c#, wpf, image, converters, bitmapimage

I am using the following code to bind an image from my database (compact sql) to my image control:

```
<Image MaxHeight="100" Stretch="UniformToFill">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage DecodePixelHeight="200" 
             StreamSource="{Binding ImageData}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

The reason for using `BitmapImage` is because I found that when I used image, the thumbnails presented were so large that it slowed the program down. I intend on using the `DecodePixelHeight` property within bitmapimage to allow me to use a smaller thumbnail size and hence keep my program from slowing down.

The issue I get when binding this to my image is an error saying I have not set `StreamSource` correctly. I have a feeling this is because my image is stored as bytes in the database (converted before hand) and that `BitmapImage` (unlike the standard `Image`) does not support automatic converting into an image format.
Is this correct? If so, do I simply need to implement a converter?

Comment: What is the type of image data?

Comment: edit: Sorry I have it as binary within my schema, but I had to change it to type 'image' on my database manually for some reason I can't remember. All I know is that I have it working fine when using a normal image control, but not with a bitmapimage control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you face is most probably related to a fact that your `ImageData` is not type of `Stream`, which is actually required by the `StremSource` property.

The hypothetical code, could be something like this:

```
Byte[] imagesBytes = GetBytesOfImageFromDB();
ImageData= new MemoryStream(imagesBytes);
```

Assuming that in this case `ImageData` model viewer property is of type `Stream`.

Hope this helps.